# BitConverter.GetBytes() showing incorrect value?

Tags: c#, math, floating-point, binary, .net-4.7.2

I'm trying to look at how a `System.Single` value is represented in memory.

From what I've read, `System.Single` is represented like this:

1 sign bit (s), 23 bit fractional significand (f) and a 8 bit biased exponent (e).

```
(-1)^s * 1.f * 2^(e-127)
```

In the case of 16777216 , `s = 0, f = 00000000000000000000000` (23 zeros), `e = 151 = 10010111`

ie. `1.00000000000000000000000 * 2^24`

In memory, I'd expect it to look like this (sign bit, fractional significand, biased exponent):

```
 0 00000000000000000000000 10010111
```

Or in bytes:

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 10010111
```

But instead it's giving me this:

```
00000000 00000000 10000000 01001011
```

Looks like the last bit is missing from the biased exponent, and a random 1 at the start of the 3rd byte, why is this?

I was able to find the right exponent by reversing the bits in each byte:

```
00000000 00000000 00000001 11010010
```

Taking the last 9 bits and reversing those again:

```
00000000 00000000 0000000 010010111
```

This is now equal to what I'd expect, but what is with this strange order?

What format is this binary number stored in?

Here's my code:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace SinglePrecision
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Single a = 16777216;            
            byte[] aBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(a);
            string s = string.Join(" ", aBytes.Select(x => Convert.ToString(x, 2).PadLeft(8, '0')));
            //s = 00000000 00000000 10000000 01001011
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The order of bytes in the array returned by the GetBytes method depends on whether the computer architecture is little-endian or big-endian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you got the [order of the parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_single-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary32) wrong. It is sign bit `s`, then exponent `e`, then fraction `f`, so your binary representation, which you otherwise calculated correctly, would be

```
0 10010111 00000000000000000000000
s e        f
```

These bits are stored in 4 continuous bytes of memory:

```
01001011 10000000 00000000 00000000
se        f
byte1    byte2    byte3    byte4
```

but because your system is [little-endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness), they are stored in reverse order:

```
00000000 00000000 10000000 01001011
byte4    byte3    byte2    byte1
```

Endiannes reverses the order of bytes, but it does not reverse the order of bits within a byte.

The *rightmost* byte is the first logical byte of the float value, and its *leftmost* bit is the sign bit, which is `0`.
The second from the right byte is the second logical byte, and its *lefmost* bit is the *last* bit of your exponent.